# Card Game: nextPlayer and invoking determineWinner

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm in need of some assistance. I'm working on a BlackJack game and I'm having difficulty with the logic of the state of the game and when to determine a winner.  I keep running into edge cases where either the browser freezes because of an infinite while loop or a stalemate where determineWinner is not invoked correctly...

I have tried using different boolean conditions depending on the player state, such as
this.hasBlackJack = false | true   where   this.cards.length === 2 && this.total() === 2
this.hasBusted = false | true  where this.total() > 21
this.hasStood = false | true where player has elected or AI probability to bust is > 50%

I also, currently, have tried simplifying the check to isEligible as seen below...

I would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction!

(I work 2 jobs, so I'm always working on this when I"m already pretty tired. I am sure I'm missing the obvious at this point.. )

In class BlackJack

```
nextPlayer() {
  const activePlayer = this.getActivePlayer();
  console.log(activePlayer.name + ': ' + activePlayer.total())
  activePlayer.deactivate();

  let indexCurrentPlayer = this.players.indexOf(activePlayer);
  let indexNextPlayer = (indexCurrentPlayer - 1 + this.players.length) % this.players.length;

  // Find the next eligible player who has not busted
  const eligiblePlayers = this.players.filter(player => player.isEligible);
  let nextEligiblePlayer = eligiblePlayers[indexNextPlayer];

  // Continue finding the next eligible player
  while (!nextEligiblePlayer && eligiblePlayers.length > 0) {
    indexNextPlayer = (indexNextPlayer - 1 + this.players.length) % this.players.length;
    nextEligiblePlayer = eligiblePlayers[indexNextPlayer];
  }

  if (nextEligiblePlayer) {
    nextEligiblePlayer.activate();
  } else {
    // If there are no eligible players left, determine the winner
    const remainingPlayers = this.players.filter(player => player.isEligible);
    if (remainingPlayers.length === 0) {
      this.determineWinner();
    }
  }
}
```

In class Player

```
class Player {
  constructor(playerName, isAI, app) {
    this.isAI = isAI;
    this.AI_delayID = null;
    this.app = app;
    this.name = playerName;
    this.cards = [];
    this.template = new PlayerTemplate();
    this.isActive = false;
    this.isEligible = true;
  }

  activate() {
    this.isActive = true;
    this.turn();
  }

  turn() {
    const shouldHit = (this.total() < 21) && (this.calcBustProbability() < 0.5);

    if (this.isAI) {
      this.AI_delayID = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.name === 'House' && this.total() === 17) {
          this.stand();
        }

        if (this.total() === 21) {
          this.has21();
        }

        if (this.total() < 21 && shouldHit) {
          this.app.renderDeal();
        } else if (this.total() > 21) {
          this.bust();
        } else {
          console.log(this.name + ' elected to STAND');
          this.stand();
        }
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      if (this.total() > 21) {
        this.bust();
      } else if (this.total() === 21) {
        this.has21();
      }
    }
  }

  calcBustProbability() {
    const numCardsRemain = this.app.blackjack.deck.getCardsRemaining();
    const currTotal = this.total();
    let bustCount = 0;

    for (let card of numCardsRemain) {
      const newTotal = currTotal + card.getValue();
      if (newTotal > 21) {
        bustCount++;
      }
    }
    const probability = bustCount / numCardsRemain.length;
    return probability;
  }

  bust() {
    console.log(this.name + ' BUSTED');
    this.isEligible = false;
    if (this.isAI) {
      clearTimeout(this.AI_delayID);
    }
    this.app.blackjack.nextPlayer();
  }

  stand() {
    console.log(this.name + ' STOOD');
    this.isEligible = false;
    if (this.isAI) {
      clearTimeout(this.AI_delayID);
    }
    this.app.blackjack.nextPlayer();
  }

  has21() {
    console.log(this.name + ' has 21');
    this.hasBlackJack = true;
    if (this.isAI) {
      this.app.blackjack.nextPlayer();
      clearTimeout(this.AI_delayID);
    }
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.isActive = false;
  }

  hit(card) {
    this.cards.push(card);
    this.renderCard();
    if (this.isAI) {
      this.app.blackjack.nextPlayer();
      clearTimeout(this.AI_delayID);
    }
  }

  total() {
    let sum = 0;
    this.cards.forEach(card => {
      sum += card.getValue();
    });
    const adjTotal = this.adjustForAces(sum);

    return adjTotal;
  }

  adjustForAces(sum) {
    let numAces = 0;
    for (const card of this.cards) {
      if (card.rank === 'A') {
        numAces++;
      }
    }

    while (numAces > 0 && sum > 21) {
      if (this.name === 'House' && numAces === 1) {
        break;
      }
      sum -= 10;
      numAces--;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```